# Prove that for every two events A and B, the probability that exactly one of the two events will occur is given by the expression

Tags: probability

Prove that for every two events $A$ and $B$, the probability that exactly one of the two events will occur is given by the expression

$P(A) + P(B) − 2 P(A \cap B)$.

My professor said that you should combine the equations for a and b which are $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B')$ and $P(B) = P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A')$

Not sure how combining the two will get the answer

Comment: I feel like your professor's explanation is rather incomplete. Do you know how to write the event of exactly one of $A$ and $B$ using unions and intersections?

Comment: well technically a = (a intersect b) union (a intersect b complement)

Comment: That's correct and all, but can you write **EXACTLY ONE** of $A$ and $B$ using unions and intersections? If you use a two-circle Venn diagram, this should be easy to visualize.

Comment: I would do P(A) intersect complement of middle part intersect complement of b part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so much combining the two, but rather that they are alternate paths to the answer.

The event that *exactly* one of the two will occur is the event of the symmetric difference. There are two equivalent expressions for this.

Then we use the *additivity of probability for unions of disjoint events*.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\Delta B) =~& \mathsf P((A\cap B^\complement)\cup(B\cap A^\complement)) 
&=~& \mathsf P((A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^\complement)
\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)
& =~& \mathsf P(A\cup B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)
\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-2~\mathsf P(A\cap B)
& =~& \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-2~\mathsf P(A\cap B)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it going left to right? I'm a little confused about how to read it

Comment: Up to down, via two paths.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

This is the event of exactly one of $A$ and $B$.

[image]

How do you represent this using unions and intersections?