# Determine the value of Pr(B ∩ $A^c$)

Tags: probability

Consider two events A and B such that

Pr(A) = 1/3 and Pr(B) = 1/2.

Determine
the value of Pr(B ∩ $A^c$) for each of the following conditions:

(a) A and B are disjoint;

(b) A ⊆ B;

(c) Pr(A ∩ B) = 1/8.

Comment: Consider drawing venn diagrams of $A$ and $B$ for each subproblem and consider set $A$ and $B$'s relative positions. It makes tackling the problem a little more tangible!

Comment: Are you the same person as the person who asked [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914779/prove-that-for-every-two-events-a-and-b-the-probability-that-exactly-one-of-the/1914795#1914795)? Duplicate accounts aren't allowed. I have reason to believe that both accounts are the same, because they seem to be typeset very similarly, with no (initial) work attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$Pr(B \cap A^c)=Pr(B)-Pr(A \cap B)$$

If you know the value of $Pr(A \cap B)$, you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Good answer, everything falls appart from there.

Answer (score 0):

(a) $B \subset A^c$, so $Pr(B \cap A^c) = Pr(A^c) = 1-Pr(A)=\frac{2}{3}$

(b) $A \subset B$, so $Pr(B \cap A^c) = Pr(B) - Pr(A) = \frac{1}{6}$

(c) $Pr(B \cap A^c) = Pr(B)-Pr(A \cap B) = \frac{3}{8}$

I hope your teachers are happy, you should really work on this on your own. This is most basic calculus, If you don't understand this, you will have no chance to understand any of the more complicated stuff wich is garanteed to come.

Comment: I don't understand how you've come to the formula are there any preliminary steps?

Comment: Read SiongthyeGohs answer.